# Single GWT Listbox won't accept CSS, but overriding all GWT Listboxes works

Tags: java, css, gwt, listbox, uibinder

I am using GWT to work on a web application in which several listboxes are used for various things. I want to change the background color of a specific listbox (to indicate that it's a required field for the user) using a CSS class. This is straightforward enough until the part where I find I am unable to get the listbox to adopt my CSS class at all. I'd like to note that I am using UiBinder and a mix of XML and Java to create and use application controls, and I've disabled Google's Standard theme while I've been trying to get this sorted out. Here's what I've tried in Java code so far:

```
@UiField
ListBox knownIssuesCombo;
...

public KnownIssuesPanel() {
  ...
  knownIssuesCombo = new ListBox();
  knownIssuesCombo.addStyleName("requiredField"); //This should work!!!
  //knownIssuesCombo.addStyleDependentName("-requiredField");
  //knownIssuesCombo.setStyleName("requiredField", true);
  //knownIssuesCombo.setStyleDependentName("-requiredField", true);
}
```

And the matching CSS:

```
.requiredField {
    background-color: Green;
}

.gwt-ListBox-requiredField {
    background-color: Green;
}
```

I CAN actually change the appearance of all of the listboxes in my application by overriding GWT's CSS like so:

```
.gwt-Listbox {
    background-color: Green;
}
```

But I don't want to make ALL of my listboxes green; I just want to affect a single, specific one. Any help or insight into this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a *basic* specificity issue (your browser dev tools should help you find it); basically you probably have a `background-color` for `.gwt-ListBox` that's being defined *after* (after in the same CSS file, or in a second file loaded after the one that contains: ) the `background-color` for `.requiredField`, and because the `.gwt-ListBox` and `.requiredField` selectors have the same [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity), the latter one wins.

Solutions:

- make sure `.requiredField` appears/is loaded after `.gwt-ListBox`
- or use a selector that is more specific than `.gwt-ListBox`, e.g. `.gwt-ListBox.requiredField`
- or use a [*dependent style name*](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#addStyleDependentName%28java.lang.String%29) (`addStyleDependentName("required")` and a `.gwt-ListBox-required` selector)

Note: `!important` will work but is bad practice (reasons are rooted in accessibility, and user choice (user-specific stylesheets))

Comment: This is not the exact answer to what the problem was, but it is close enough that I'll accept it as the answer. Essentially, I think it was an issue with the order in which the styles were being applied, which is what your solution mentions in the first bullet point. What I ended up doing was defining a CSS class in the CSS file as normal, and then used a CSSResource extender with my ClientBundle and used the addStyleNames attribute/method in the UiBinder XML files to actually apply the style to the component. I hope this makes sense to whoever runs into this problem and finds this answer!

Comment: "an issue with the order in which the styles were being applied" is what I describes in the first paragraph. When selectors have the same specificity, the rules are applied in the order they appear in the stylesheet (when in the same stylesheet), in the order the stylesheets appear in the document (when in separate stylesheets); so your `background-color` for `.gwt-ListBox` overrode the one for `.requiredField`. It's hard to answer more specifically without knowing how the stylesheets have been loaded though (`CssResource`? `<link rel=stylesheet>`?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
background: green !important;
```

Comment: I guess I should've mentioned that I've also already tried all the variations of the code that I originally posted, meaning I've messed with background, background-color, color, and have added and removed the !important flag. I did try this variation again using addStyleName to no effect. Thanks for trying though

Answer (score 0):

I think the listbox by default gets the class of "gwt-ListBox". When you add a name instead of setting the primary style name, the new class gets concatenated with a space, not a hyphen.

So instead of

```
.gwt-ListBox-requiredField {
    background-color: Green;
}
```

Try

```
.gwt-ListBox requiredField {
    background-color: Green;
}
```

I think. :)

I believe you can also just setPrimaryStyleName and then your initial requiredField tag will work, but I have yet to use that one. Try them and let me know what works.

Comment: The first suggestion (use a space instead of a -) did not work in conjunction with the addStyleName method (and probably all of the other methods because they have all behaved the same in my experiences thus far); the second suggestion would nuke the styling I get (and still want) by using Google's standard theme. Thanks though